# Add collapse event to the GWT - GXT combo box

Tags: gwt, gxt

Even though the requirement is simple, I feel that this is eating my time, i'm trying to add a collapse event to the gwt gxt combobox, i'm using the version 2.1 gwt. Any small snippet will be helpful. the version of the library that i have do not support addCollapsehandler event, i've tried to do with addHandler, i do not know how to proceed on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the normal way to do that:

```
Listener<FieldEvent> collapseListener = new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
    @Override void handleEvent(FieldEvent fe) {
            // collapse handler here
    }
}

comboBox.addListener(Events.Collapse, collapseListener);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.  Is there a standard API that you follow? Looks like there are a lot of versions of APIS for the GWT-GXT.